# How to retrieve top 5 values from each column of each of the table of same database and then get over all top 5 in the whole database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have an database of 2000 tables and they seems increasing as each table represent a user.So structure of all tables is same.

i want to get top 5 values 
e.g if we take column -> OS(operating system)
then 
query should take top 5 operating systems names from each table with their count and in the end i should get the sum up result of all tables to get overall top 5 operating systems names in all tables of database..

how to do it ?

i can use PHP & MySQL only

i have fetched the same column from all tables but can't access the values stored in them..

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'os'
```

Comment: Why on the earth do you need to have one table per user? It is extremely bad architecture, I just cannot imagine any scenario there it can be useful.

Comment: i know but its like this only can you suggest something ?

Comment: This is tagged with `mysql` and with `sql-server`, but you write "PHP & MySQL only"... Please clearify the RDBMS (product and version)! Your posted `SELECT ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA ...` looks like SQL Server...

Comment: @Shnugo i have an MYSQL db   -_-

Comment: 2000+ tables! Wow - you need to redesign your schema as a matter of urgency. One table for users with other tables, linked to the users table by keys is the general basis for a properaly structured db - the `R` in `RDBMS` stands for `relational` afterall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is really something you should change, but this was an approach to do this in MySql. Test it [in this Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df224/30)

```
create table test(os int);
insert into test SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3;

create table test2(os int);
insert into test2 SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13;

create table test3(os int);
insert into test3 SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23;

create table testOtherColumn(Other int);
insert into testOtherColumn SELECT 101 UNION SELECT 102 UNION SELECT 103;

set @MyCmd=
concat(
(
  select substr(group_concat(' UNION SELECT ',c.COLUMN_NAME,' FROM ',c.TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR ''),8) 
  from information_schema.columns as c
  where c.COLUMN_NAME='os'
),';');

select @MyCmd;

PREPARE MyStatement FROM @MyCmd;
EXECUTE MyStatement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE myStatement;
```

You will need some kind of sorting and `LIMIT x` and aggregats to achieve your goal. I just do not know enough of your tables structures...